# Login issue in pootle

Tags: python, django, pootle

I have installed pootle as per [instructions](http://pootle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server/installation.html#running-pootle)

And after strating server I can access it at localhost:8000 but when I trying to login with the user i have created while installing(superuser) , its not getting logged in . When I checked the console I am getting this error `{"msg": "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable"}` .

I am using Sqlite as database. I have just installed it , syncdb and then start nothing more .I have changed anything in config file too.Do I need to configure something else.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you check all the [Django-specific `EMAIL_*` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#email-backend), especially those concerning hosts and ports — it might be that your provider is blocking SMTP requests.